# htaccess redirect .PDF for Prevent Direct Access but visible in internal viewer

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pdf, redirect

I'm developing with a small web-based project with `WordPress` which contains a lot of PDF files. What I'm looking for is to **close the direct access to PDF files**, like in `https://sciami.com/scm-content/uploads/2018/06/myfile.pdf` **and redirect the request to the attachment page** in `https://sciami.com/myfile`.

To do this, I wrote a code in `.htaccess` as below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^scm-content/uploads/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)\.pdf$ /$3 [R=301,L]
```

In this way all PDFs are redirected to related attachment page (and it works!). Inside the attachment page, there is a PDF viewer that shows related PDF file. But because of the rule written in the .htaccess, the PDF viewer doesn't show anything because the `https://sciami.com/scm-content/uploads/2018/06/myfile.pdf` URL necessary for show PDF is rewritten.

**My question is how to close the direct access to PDFs, while allowing them to be loaded within the viewer**?
The condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www.)?sciami.com/ [NC]
```

allows operation within the site, but prevents redirect from within the site.
Every help is welcome.

Comment: There's a plugin for that - https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-direct-access/ ;-)

Comment: If you protect files with this plugin, they can not be called from the viewer. ONLY way to access the protected file is a private download link. But I want to show it in the viewer in the attacment page.